# append() printing the complete page code on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to validate a form and append an error message if fields are left blank inside the form, I am attaching the code below

```
<form id="contact-form">
  <div id="errorArea"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Mail*">
    </div>
  </div>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject*">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Type Your Message......."></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="default-btn submit-btn bg-leaf" onclick="validate()">SEND</button>
```

I am calling the validate() function on button click which is below

```
function validate() {
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var subject = $('#subject').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();

                if(name == "" || email == "" || subject == "" || message == "") {
                    $("#errorArea").append("<p class='text-danger'>You need to fill all fields before sending an email</p>");
                }
            }
```

and now whenever I click the button, it does show the message but after the form body, it pastes the entire HTML page code there aswell, any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what the full result looks like? And is the HTML snippet above the complete block?

Comment: I don't see anything that prevents the form from submitting if the validation fails. Is the page simply reloading? Or do you get to see the error message?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `submit` value as `type` property for button. You need to use

```
onclick="return validate()"
```

in order to apply the client's validation part.

Also, you do not need to use `append` method because it will append a `DOM` structure every time you click the `SEND` button. Use `.html()` method instead by passing the *HTML* content as parameter.

```js
function validate() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();

    if(name == "" || email == "" || subject == "" || message == "") {
        $("#errorArea").html("<p class='text-danger'>You need to fill all fields before sending an email</p>");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form">
    <div id="errorArea"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Mail*">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject*">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Type Your Message......."></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="default-btn submit-btn bg-leaf" onclick="return validate()">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The "correct" (imho) way would be to use a `submit` button and only intercept the `submit` event so the form would also work without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach to not allow empty fields would be to add the attribute **required** to every input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*" required>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Mail*" required>
```

Answer (score -4):

You are missing to add javascript lib file, you can see into browser console it give error live **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**. [image: ReferenceError: $ is not defined]. please add jquery into top of file then try it.

Comment: How do you know that they haven't included jQuery?